# GLSL shaders does not work using 327.24 drivers version with a GeForce GTX 670M

Tags: opengl, drivers

I develop a 3D engine using GLSL shaders. I downloaded the last NVIDIA driver for the GeForce GTX 670M. The problem is at the execution. I have the following error message :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000007F9B4F96E82 (ig7icd64.dll) in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000004A31EC0.
```

The laptop name :

```
TOSHIBA Qosmio x870
```

Here's my laptop technical description :

```
Vendor : TOSHIBA
Processor : Intel (R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz 2.40GHz
System type : 64 bits
```

Here's my graphics configuration :

```
GL Vendor : Intel
GL Renderer : Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000
GL Version : 4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2875
GL Version : 4.0
GLSL Version : 4.00 - Build 9.17.10.2875
```

According to the call stack (on Visual Studio 2012), the problem comes from the first call of the 'glUseProgram' function, so where the program shader must be used. So I think the problem comes from the new version of the driver I've downloaded. Does anyone already have encountered this problem ?

Comment: `ig7icd64.dll` is actually the name of Intel's driver. I have to assume you are running on a laptop that uses nVIDIA Optimus? For whatever reason your application appears to be running using the integrated GPU, but this in itself should not be a problem, because Intel also implements GLSL. Perhaps you are encountering dynamic switching at run-time? If you could include more information, particularly things like the strings: `GL_RENDERER` and `GL_VERSION` that would help.

Comment: Sorry for the missing elements. I updated my post. I hope it's clearer  like this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is definitely an Optimus issue, though I cannot say what is causing it. Can you try disabling dynamic GPU switching in your display driver settings?